# Can i open js file within IDE by cshtml template

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there any way to open js|css files within visual studio by the path in the cshtml template file?

Example:

```
<html>
...
<script type=""text/javascript"" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/script/file.js")" />
...
</html>
```

Can you open the file (/Content/script/file.js) by clicking the path?

thanks

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide a little more detail to your question.

Comment: Can you clarify that you want to click on the path and have the file open?

Comment: FYI, your quotes are wrong: should be <script type="text/javascript". . . and "@Url.Content('~/Content/script/file.js')" . . .

Comment: I would have the same functionality as "Go to Definition (F12)" to open the .js file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about a Visual Studio feature to open the script file when you click the URL in the editor? As far as I know, it doesn't do that now. However, you can suggest it as a possible future feature at the Web Platform team's user voice site: http://aspnet.uservoice.com.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, i go to do it now... And i am trying develop a plugin of vs that resolve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` just includes it in the page.  If you want a linke then use `<a>` element and set the href attribute

Comment: did you try it?  if you link to a file with <a>, it will open the file

Comment: does not work with tag <a>
`<a href="~/Content/script/file.js"></a>`

Comment: Would be nice, an extension for visual studio. But what? :D

Comment: <a href="@Url.Content("~/Content/script/file.js")">test</a>.  Make sure to include the @url and put something between the begin and end <a> and </a>.